# Prevent tabs from showing as a drop-down list when on landscape? (Android Appcelerator Titanium)

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator

If an app is on portrait, tabs will be showing below the ActionBar, but if the app is on landscape, tabs will be on a drop-down list:

[image: landscape behaviour]

Is there any way to prevent this behaviour? On landscape, I would like to see the tabs just like in potrait mode:

[image: portrait behaviour]

Comment: I guess this property can help you **[Titanium Android ActionBar NavigationMode](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Android.ActionBar-property-navigationMode)**